# Consistency in inputs (number of characters you can visible write)

Tags: html, css, browser, input, cross-browser

Why can't I've consistency among those inputs? (number of characters)

```css
.input { width: 200px; }
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text">
```

Regarding firefox and chrome, copying and the paste the same text gives me a different number of visible characters available.

The text: HAHAHA HAHAHA HAHAHA HAHA. In firefox it's fits perfect, but in chrome it overlaps 2 chars. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ucr8pq5/

Screenshots:

- Firefox:
  [image]
- Chrome:
  [image]

Tried:

- css reset
- change line-height of the input
- maintain the same font

Comment: Have you tried adding a size?  `<input type="text" size={yourSize} ... />`

Comment: Size doesn't work either. But the thing is: why can't I've an exact number of visible characters in any browser? My width isn't enough? Font problem? (No, in my research) What is the problem that I can't see

Comment: It's probably some default settings, some very annoying default settings.

Comment: Can you post screenshots to describe what you mean by *perfect* and *overlaps*?

Comment: To keep the chars width consistency can be very hard cross browsers and OS, I'd say impossible, my advice is - don't go crazy for trying it.

Comment: This is why I can't be a designer. Those bugged fluffy things.